# Выбор конкретной конфигурации маппера

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Допустим, у меня есть сервисы, которые на вход принимают IMapper.

В контексте одного сервиса объекты должны мапиться по одному, а в контексте другого по другому.

Поэтому я создаю 2 профиля.

Теперь вопрос, в том, а как мне в корне композиции внедрения зависимостей сказать, что тут нужно разрешить зависимость с одним профилем, а тут с другим?

Comment: Думаю, Automapper такое не умеет. Можно попробовать написать обертку над `IMapper<T>`, где T - тип сервиса (либо тип профиля). Ну и соответственно регистрировать в контейнере зависимостей два разных маппера.

Answer (score 0):

Например это можно сделать так, в первом сервисе:

```
    services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
     {
        cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfileOne());
     });
```

во втором сервисе:

```
    services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
     {
        cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfileTwo());
     });
```

Соответственно в первом сервисе у вас будет работать `MappingProfileOne` а во втором `MappingProfileTwo`
Соответствующие расширения объявлены в сборках AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
и Automapper. Их можно добавить через nuget.

Если этот вариант не поможет, пожалуйста дайте больше контекста, что за приложение и как вы инициализируете его.

Comment: Как ваш ответ отвечает на `Теперь вопрос, в том, а как мне в корне композиции внедрения зависимостей сказать, что тут нужно разрешить зависимость с одним профилем, а тут с другим?`?

Comment: @tym32167 Дополнил ответ. Если нужны дополнительные уточнения, покажите пример кода. Возможно у нас проблема в терминах.

Comment: я думаю, что автор вопроса под сервисом подразумевает класс-сервис, а ну проект-сервис.

Comment: @tym32167 Возможною Давайте посмотрим, что ответит автор. Если у вас будет ответ для уровня классов - буду рад увидеть, но у меня ощущение, что если в рамках одного проекта одна и та же пара сущностей должна мапиться по разному, в зависимости от того, в каком классе это происходит, то тут проблема  с дизайном классов. Возможно должно быть не 2 а 3 сущности.